# How to get Neo4jTemplate in SDN4

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-data-neo4j-4

I am using Spring Data Neo4j 4(SDN4) from the example project SDN4-northwind(https://github.com/amorgner/sdn4-northwind)，when I try to get the Neo4jTemplate bean，I get the error message like this.
Does anyone know how to get the Neo4jTemplate bean from SDN4?

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.data.neo4j.template.Neo4jTemplate] is defined
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:371)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:331)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:968)
at org.neo4j.example.northwind.Run.main(Run.java:34)
```

Here is the Configuration file

```
package org.neo4j.example.northwind;

import org.neo4j.ogm.session.Session;
import org.neo4j.ogm.session.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.config.Neo4jConfiguration;
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.config.EnableNeo4jRepositories;
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.server.Neo4jServer;
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.server.RemoteServer;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;


@Configuration
@EnableNeo4jRepositories("org.neo4j.example.northwind.repository")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class AppContext extends Neo4jConfiguration {

public static final String NEO4J_HOST = "http://localhost:";
public static final int    NEO4J_PORT = 7474;

@Override
public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    System.setProperty("username", "neo4j");
    System.setProperty("password", System.getProperty("password","osp"));
    return new SessionFactory("org.neo4j.example.northwind.model");
}

@Bean
@Override
public Neo4jServer neo4jServer() {
    return new RemoteServer(NEO4J_HOST + NEO4J_PORT);
}

@Bean
@Override
//@Scope(value = "session", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public Session getSession() throws Exception {
    return super.getSession();
}

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assdd

```
@Bean
 public Neo4jOperations getNeo4jTemplate() throws Exception {
     return new Neo4jTemplate(getSession());
 }
```

to `AppContext` and then `@Autowired Neo4jOperations neo4jTemplate;`

Comment: it works, thank you @Luanne. 
May I know why I should use Neo4jOperations  instead of Neo4jTemplate to be the bean type ?

Comment: Believe you've got to use the interface. Neo4jOperations is the interface for  Neo4jTemplate